# Is there an option to minimize TweetDeck to tray?

Tags: twitter, tweetdeck

Until today I used Twhirl, but I want to give TweetDeck a chance.

However, it seems that I can only either minimize it to the task bar or close it; both options aren't ideal.

Is there an option to minimize TweetDeck to a tray icon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plenty of ways to skin this cat if the program doesn't offer the feature 'Minimize to Tray':

[**TrayIt!**](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Desktop-Enhancements/Other-Desktop-Enhancements/TrayIt.shtml) will do the trick.

[image]

[**TaskswitcherXP**](http://www.ntwind.com/software/taskswitchxp.html) can also minimize any application to the system tray (but as the name implies, only works for XP)

[image]

And then there is [**Pitaschio**](http://pitaschio.ara3.net/) which can also 'Minimize to Tray'. i'm using it to tray email clients and web browsers.

[image]

Of course all these programs are free.

Answer (score 1):

Not from within the program itself, it seems to have been [taken out](http://tweetdeck.uservoice.com/pages/1192-general/suggestions/10034-minimize-to-tray) for some reason. Although you can use [Tray It!](http://www.teamcti.com/trayit/trayit.htm) to send any app to the tray:

[image]

[image]